# Enabled touch id and face id in the app

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id, face-id

How do we know that the application has already enabled touch or face id?Right now I am using Biometric Authentication CocoPod to integrate this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalAuthentication with LAContext, it will do the job and tell you everything you want to know about device biometry state. You can use this singleton class for starting point:

```
import LocalAuthentication

final public class BiometryManager {
    public typealias SuccessComplition = () -> Void
    public typealias ErrorComplition = (Error?) -> Void

    public static let shared = BiometryManager()
    private let context = LAContext()

    private init() { }

    public var biometryType: LABiometryType {
        var error: NSError?

        guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
            return LABiometryType.LABiometryNone
        }

        return context.biometryType
    }

    public func authenticate(successComplition: @escaping SuccessComplition, errorComplition: @escaping ErrorComplition) {
        var error: NSError?
        let reasonString = "provide reason text"

        guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
            errorComplition(error)
            return
        }

        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: { (success, evalPolicyError) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    successComplition()
                } else {
                    errorComplition(evalPolicyError)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The class is available from iOS 11 and it will tell you about device biometryType and you can also call authenticate method. If it returns error, you can cast it to LAError and get more specific error codes from it. Hope it helps.

Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/laerror

You can add this property to above class to check the biometry availability:

```
public var isAvailable: Bool {
    var error: NSError?

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {return true}

    guard let laError = error as? LAError else {return false}

// Check the laError.code, maybe its locked or something else and make specific decision
}
```

Comment: Good one though... I am more concerned about how do I know whether my app is enabled with the touch or face id